# Can Python be used to create multiplayer browser-based games?

Tags: python, sockets

I am interested in creating a multiplayer browser-based game for academic research, but am mainly competent in Python (with experience in PyGame).

I am aware of PyJS (http://pyjs.org/), but am not sure if that can handle  asynchronous, multiplayer collaboration.

Is this doable in Python?

Comment: I don't know if it's doable, but even if it is you should consider another language.

Comment: Python is Turing complete, so yes.

Comment: Recommend you ask these sort of questions on [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com), instead of SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pygame will be of no use to you here.  You could probably do it ([sockets](/questions/tagged/sockets) won't be very useful to you either) I don't suggest it though.

If you learned JavaScript you would find your task much easier.  Creating a game would require a canvas and that is JavaScript's specialty, even the web-frameworks such as Flask and Django don't inplament them, so eventually you will probably find yourself writing a lot of JavaScript anyway, games are very complex sooner or later your will find some hitch that will not be inplamented and will be forced into writing JS anyway.

Then you would probably need logins or a way to save scores.  This is where Python can be useful, you could send all the information to be processed server-side in Python.  This has been done before and is reasonably easy.

If you are talking about a 3d game *don't*, you will need some form of 3d engine such as three.js, those will be coded in JS (you will find all online engines are inplamented in either JS or Jquery) and those will cause endless headaches if you try to use one of those in Python.

If you want to develop an online in-browser game you will need to know some JavaScript knowledge at some point or another, Python is excellent server-side and good client-side as well, however games are extremely complex at the best of times with graphics and all.  It is not like a web-page, this is an enormous task to undertake (even armed with all the web-development languages -HTML/CSS/JS/Jquery/AJAX/SQL/AngularJS this is an enormous undertaking), and using Python just makes you task much much more difficult, you will go though a lot of hassle and in the end, if you ever do survive it, it would probably have been easier to learn JS and use that.

Server-side, yes go for Python, if it is client side you need JavaScript.

If you still decide to do this start with a simple 2d single player game like flappy bird or tetris and then progress to something harder.

Comment: I'm seeking to implement a low-resolution version of Transformice (http://www.transformice.com/) minus most of the core features (just basic jumping and gravity mechanics, with chat and multiplayer ability).  Can you recommend a javascript platform?  Node.js?  What is popular nowadays?

Comment: @Parseltongue  OK, what you want to do looks do-able, if you use the right tools.  I would suggest learning JavaScript for the graphics, this will run client side (in the users browser) [here is an example]( https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp) of a simple JavaScript game, for the multiplayer part probably use angularJS (this is more of a programming technique rather  than a language)

Comment: This will allow you to update the game without reloading.  You will need to send all the player info scores/distance/info to the servers, you could do this with forms.   You can do this via [http forms](https://knowledge.kitchen/Sending_data_from_client_to_server) once again this can be done in JavaScript but you may be able to inplament in Python (the first would probably be easier). Next you send all the info and process it server side.  A SQL (database) is highly recommended although you may be able to inplament something yourself for storage.

Comment: Next use Python (cgi programming or other) to send all the info to the the players, you will need a list of all the users to send all the data to (SQL database is used for storage).  Node.js can do the same thing as Python, since you already know Python I would suggest learn maybe a web framework, you will need to learn some form handling libraries and data processing/storage libraries. Although you might decide it's worth using https://vizteck.com/blog/node-js-vs-python-best-option-startup/

Comment: Both Node.js and Python can be used server side, you have the choice of any server side language.

Comment: Thanks so much @Simon!

Comment: @Parseltongue No problem.  Good luck with your project. :-)